# Android 11 Accessibility Service Permissions

Tags: android, android-permissions, accessibilityservice, accessibility, android-11

Can anyone explain what is going to happen with accessibility actions/permissions with android 11? As now i am using accessibility service to do some stuff without user interference on third party applications. eg. Whatsapp.  For example i am trying to build a voice assistant kind of app which is taking user input through Google's speech api, and identify the commands then based on that commands, perform action in whatsapp using accessibility service.This thing is working pretty well up to android 10. So what changes i can expect from android 11 in this flow ?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. Just add the below line to Your code.

```
@Override
protected void onServiceConnected() {
AccessibilityServiceInfo info = new AccessibilityServiceInfo();
info.packageNames = new String[]{"com.whatsapp"};
this.setServiceInfo(info)
};
```